# What 3-input logic gate is this?

Tags: logic-gates

I was experimenting with logic gates on my breadboard and tried a 3-input logic gate.

I got the following result:

```
Input  |  Output
A B C  |   ?
0 0 0  |   1
0 0 1  |   0
0 1 0  |   1
0 1 1  |   0
1 0 0  |   1
1 0 1  |   0
1 1 0  |   1
1 1 1  |   1
```

What logic gate could this be? Thanks

Comment: What is the part number and pinout? Photo?

Comment: nC+A.B is the function.

Comment: @Transistor sorry, what do you mean part number and pinout? I've built a transistor logic gate if that helps...

Comment: @Andyaka oh! Is there a specific name given to this function

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: @Mi hirChaturvedi: When you said "*... and tried a 3-input logic gate*" I read it as you were probing one gate. I think you have created some combinational logic rather than a logic "gate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally it is this: -

[image]

And it doesn't have a specific name unless someone somewhere in some obscure place has named it.

Comment: C looks like enable. Kind of nand with enable.

Comment: Thanks! It does output exactly the same values. How did you figure it out though?

Comment: The output is the inverse of C except for one instant.